# how to avoid synchronous request with implicitly called delegate methods (parse + swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Normally if I depend on the results from a parse request, I will call the function that needs them in the success block of the request, like so:

```
query?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({
(object:PFObject?,error:NSError?) in
    if error == nil{
        var image = (object as! PFUser).avatarImage
        ATLIncomingMessageCollectionViewCell.appearance().avatarImageView.image = image
        completion(data:image) 
    }   
})
```

However, in this case, I am using a framework for messages (Layer + Atlas), and my problem happens when I tap on a conversation in a tableview. In order to load the custom user avatars for the conversation, I have to query Parse for the users in question.

Here is the delegate function that sets the avatar when I click on a conversation:

```
func conversationListViewController(conversationListViewController: ATLConversationListViewController!, avatarItemForConversation conversation: LYRConversation!) -> ATLAvatarItem! {

    var query = LYRQuery(queryableClass: LYRMessage.self)
    query.predicate = LYRPredicate(property: "conversation", predicateOperator: LYRPredicateOperator.IsEqualTo, value: conversation)
    var messages:NSOrderedSet = self.layerClient.executeQuery(query, error: nil)
    var message = messages.lastObject as! LYRMessage
    var participantID = message.sender.userID
    if(appdelegate.layerClient.authenticatedUserID != participantID)
    {
        var object:PFUser = PFUser(withoutDataWithObjectId: participantID)
        object.fetchIfNeeded()
        return object
    }
    return PFUser.currentUser() as? ATLParticipant
}
```

And here is what my ATLParticipant looks like (sans some extraneous code):

```
extension PFUser: ATLParticipant {

    public var participantIdentifier: String {
        return self.objectId!
    }

    public var avatarImage: UIImage? {
        let image = (self.valueForKey("profilePictureLarge") as! PFFile)
        var mainImage = UIImage(data:image.getData()!)
        return mainImage
    }
}
```

The problem is that the synchronous requests, getData() and fetchIfNeeded() block the main thread and freeze the UI until they complete. This is obviously bad from a design standpoint, but I'm not sure there is a way around it.

To articulate the problem a little more clearly:

1) I click on a conversation and the delegate methods for my tableview fetch the information about the conversation. Then the conversation is opened in a different view controller.

2) Some of the info needed has to be retrieved from Parse, but I have no way of waiting to return from the delegate methods without a synchronous request.

3) I don't know of a way to manually set the data, else I would just use placeholders and set the real data in background.

4) I could preload all of the info I'll need, but that would become highly impractical if there were more than a few users, so I really need to get it on the fly.

I'm sure that there must be an obvious solution, but I'm still very bad at iOS programming.

Comment: You could return a placeholder image and then invalidate the placeholder later, causing `avatarImage` to be reevaluated. However at that time, you'll have the real image and can return it immediately.

Comment: @nielsbot that's what I would do if I knew how to mention it explicitly. So far the only way I know to set it is in the avatarItemForConversation function. I'm not sure how the return of this function is handled.

Comment: Do you have the source to the frameworks? You could perhaps look at their source...